# How to convert hash password in text string in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, code-first

How to convert a hashed password in text string in SQL Server 2008?

I want to know the password of user which is stored in SQL Server as hash password. How to convert hashed password to normal text?

Comment: This is not possible. Hashing a string is a one-way-thing. If you want to check if a password is correct, you have to build the hash and compare both hash-values.

Comment: Firstly, tell your boss you don't want to be in charge of security at your work place, secondly read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Answer (score -1):

thats generally not how it works.  Password checks are done on the following principal

Password -> encryption  -> saved

then when user enters a password you reencrypt it, and compare the new encrypted to the old, if its the same then you got the right password you can enter.  This stops people "finding out" other peoples passwords and keeps systems secure. Which is why often brute force password cracking is needed to get into things.

If you can unencrypt it - then there was no point storing it encrypted in the first place.

Comment: `then there was no point storing it encrypted in the first place` Well, for encrypted you would expect to be able to decrypt it. **Hashed** on the other hand... https://www.securityinnovationeurope.com/blog/page/whats-the-difference-between-hashing-and-encrypting

Comment: I was referring to "encrypted" as a generic term for making it unhumanly readable.. rather than acutal real a specific encryption that is reversible..

Answer (score -1):

you cant send a string and decrypt it, because DecryptByPassPhrase function expects a varbinary parameter.

here is a small example

```
declare @encrypt varbinary(200) 
select @encrypt = EncryptByPassPhrase('key', 'abc' )
select @encrypt 

select convert(varchar(100),DecryptByPassPhrase('key', @encrypt ))
```